# Calendar View Always shows List threshold exceeded error

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calendar, list-view-threshold, indexed-column

I am using Sharepoint 356 (office 365). I recently migrated my site from sharepoint 2007 to 365.

I used to have a calendar on my homepage that had 5800 items. Office 365 view limit is 5000. So the calendar view does not show any items. It just shows this error message

```
This view cannot be displayed because it exceeds the list view threshold (5000 items) enforced by the administrator.

To view items, try selecting another view or creating a new view. If you do not have sufficient permissions to create views for this list, ask your administrator to modify the view so that it conforms to the list view threshold.
```

I have clicked on "Modify View" and then set `Created` as `[Today]-5` which should lead to 5-10 entries. Yet on the homepage where the calendar should show the error continues to be displayed.

Why is this not taking effect?

NOTE: that i am not using Team Site. Still using the old UI of sharepoint. If i click on the View Name the next page successfully shows the items.

[image]

Comment: Can you check if `Created` column is indexed or not ?

Comment: I agree with @MonicaJagani - could you make the`Created` column indexed and retry?

Comment: `Created` is an indexed column

Comment: Are you doing this in IE?

Comment: Can you provide full CAML for the view here? There could be a hint. Also, try filtering by ID > 1000 or smth like that.

Comment: @SharePointGoa i am using Chrome. Should i be using IE?

Comment: @AlexeyKrasheninnikov what do you mean? Not sure how i get the CAML

Comment: Yes. Some of the controls gets disabled in Chrome(sometimes). Try using IE

Comment: @SharePointGoa i have tried using IE. the results are the same. I tried using Edge and the results are the same. i would be skeptical that such simple web parts would not work on chrome. Doesnt everyone use chrome?

Comment: If you are working in IE11. that too have some problem. So try adding the site in compatibility view and see if control gets enabled!

Comment: you can export the list schema that will include CAML of all views by means of URL protocol. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd587791(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Changing the view is not sufficient,  you also have to add an index to the list. 
List settings -> create an index

Comment: `created` is already an indexed column.

Answer (score 1):

Clarification questions... (too many characters for a comment)

1. Can you toggle to another view without getting the error?
2. For list indexing, try creating additional indices (event name, start date, category, etc).
3. For Page Editing: Can you navigate to a separate page and go into edit mode?  I'm assuming this is a publishing site collection.  If not, try navigating to the culprit page via Site Contents/Pages or Site Pages, select the ellipses and check the page properties, permissions.  SP Online has recently enabled a timeout function so if you're using a stale browser instance, the page may show as checked out to you, while not letting you edit.  If/when you see that, do a force refresh.

As a fallback option:

Lists created in O365 can have up to 20 million items with defined views and indexing applied. I'm not sure what the success stories are for migrated lists vs imported into new lists. Your list is behaving like a remnant.

You probably still have migration tools handy.  An option to consider is to create a new calendar in the new environment, then migrate the data from your old calendar over. Sharegate or something like it are great, especially if you already have defined content types or metadata.

I've had to do this with a few lists post-migration for various reasons, and it's not as painful as it sounds (if you have the tools for the job).

Good luck -

Comment: I have tried going into edit mode. It says "You are editing a personal version of this page"

Comment: Ok, that sounds like you are signed in as a general users.  All O365 users have the option to 'customize' the way they see their pages (to a degree, unless that's been turned off).  This wouldn't happen if you're signed in on a global admin account.    Can you go to the O365 Admin Panel, click on Users, type your name, and see what access you have?  If you don't have admin access, you won't be able to log into the O365 admin panel.  It sounds like you are on the right path, just not using an admin level account.  I hope that helps -

Comment: I checked my users permissions and it says "Global Administrator"

Comment: If you are seeing "you are editing a personal version", then you only have Contribute rights to that site.  That would explain why the item limit issue is not fully resolving.

Global Admin reflects your O365 permission level; this is not the same as your SP permission level.  That depends on how your SPO permissions are defined. 

You'll need to be in the Site Owner SP group / Full Control to manage the list and its view administratively.   Check also at the Site Collection to ensure you're in the Site Owners group.

Comment: For more information:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understanding-permission-levels-in-SharePoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848

Comment: So basically:
1.  Check permissions
2.  With full control access to site, make changes to list directly (Site Contents / Calendar Name).  
3. Create your desired view; save it.
4.  Verify indexing is on; use more than one indext
5.  Head to the page you want the calendar to display.
6. Edit page / edit web part / toggle to your new view. 
7.  Save / Publish.
Good luck, keep us posted!

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the view the calendar webpart is using.

- Edit the page
- Put the webpart in edit mode
- Modify the view and apply the filter
- Save the page

Comment: interesting... the Edit Page is disabled for me. But i am the Global adim... Any idea?

Comment: Are you accessing it via the settings menu at the top right?

Comment: no. i was doing it via the toolbar that shows at the top of the page. it has ` Browse, Page, items, list` in the top toolbar. in the  page ribbon the Edit Page is disabled

Comment: In the list tab of the ribbon there is an option to modify the view there. Is that available to you?

Comment: yes. "Modify View" is available. I have already tried that. It does not change anything. I used it to specify `created` is greater than `[Today]-5`